# How can I reload the price of product by clicking on select the quantity in table view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In this, I am clicking on update button and my price is not updating instantly, Its updating when i go back to home view controller. Please help me out of this.[I want when I click on update button, My price of product will be change according to selection of quantity like 1 kg, 2kg ,5 kg etc]

```
#import "MainCartViewController.h"
#import "CartTableCell.h"
#import "CheckOutViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "Detail.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

#define JSON_URL @"http://www.webchefz.com/Andriod/index.php?Table=Cart&UserID=11"

@interface MainCartViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainCartViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
[super viewDidLoad];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];  
 UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
 [ navBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
  UIButton *Btn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [Btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,30.0f,30.0f)];
    [Btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"carc.png"]]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [Btn addTarget:self action:@selector(AddtoCartButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:Btn];
    cFRAIPArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    tableData =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    blogURL= [NSURL URLWithString:JSON_URL];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    dataDictionary  = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    tableData = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"userlist"];
    // int tp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"TotalPrice"]];
    totalPrice= [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"userlist"]valueForKey:@"TotalPrice"];
    NSLog(@"TP IS %@", [dataDictionary valueForKey:@"TotalPrice"]);


    subtotal.text= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ Rs.",[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"TotalPrice"]];
    int ShippingValue = [[subtotal text] intValue];
    int value = 50;
    float floatNum = ShippingValue + value;

    grandTotal.text=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.1f Rs.", floatNum];
    NSLog(@"dwfefefeusers are %@",  totalPrice);
    NSLog(@"dwfefefeusers are %@",  tableData);
    NSString *items= [[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"userlist"]valueForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"hjdbhsdbchjds%@",items
          );


    for (dataDictionary in tableData)
    {

        //        currentHotel=  [[Detail alloc]initWithId:[[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue] Name:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] HindiName:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"HindiName"] MRP:[[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"MRP"]integerValue] ImagePath:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"ImagePath"]Category:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"Category"]];
        currentHotel = [[Detail alloc]initWithId:[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ID"]integerValue] Name:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] HindiName:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"HindiName"] MRP:[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"TotalPrice"]integerValue] CartID:[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"CartID"]integerValue] ProductID:[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ProductID"]integerValue] Quantity:[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Quantity"]integerValue] userName:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"UserName"] ImagePath:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"ImagePath"] Category:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"Category"]];


        [self.objectHolderArray addObject:currentHotel];

    }

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    label.text = @"Cart List";
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:16];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
    //    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    // Initialize table data
    //    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}

-(NSMutableArray *)objectHolderArray
{
    if(!_objectHolderArray) _objectHolderArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return _objectHolderArray;
}


IBAction)AddtoCartButton:(id)sender
{
    MainCartViewController *cartView= [[MainCartViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainCartViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cartView animated:YES];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CartTableCell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CartTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }



    currentHotel = [self.objectHolderArray
                    objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.objectHolderArray
                 objectAtIndex:indexPath.item] );
    cell.nameLabel.text=currentHotel.name;


    cell.MRPLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs.%d",currentHotel.MRP];
    NSLog(@"price is %@",cell.MRPLabel.text);
    [cell.thumbnailImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentHotel.images] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultPlayerImge.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached|SDWebImageProgressiveDownload];


    [cell.deleteBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteProduct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.deleteBtn.tag = [indexPath row];
    [cell.PickerBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(createPickerView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.PickerBtn.tag = [indexPath row];

    [cell.updateBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(updateProduct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.updateBtn.tag = [indexPath row];

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (debtn.deleteBtn.highlighted) {
        NSLog(@"cff");
    }
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.objectHolderArray count];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{



    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

    int errorCode = httpResponse.statusCode;

    NSString *fileMIMEType = [[httpResponse MIMEType] lowercaseString];

    NSLog(@"response is %d, %@", errorCode, fileMIMEType);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    NSLog(@"data is %@", data);

    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"string is %@", myString);

    NSError *e = nil;

    flickrDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

    NSLog(@"dictionary is %@", flickrDictionary);

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {



    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",

          [error localizedDescription],

          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {



            [HUD hide:YES];


            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Quanity updated succesfully" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
    [self.tableView1 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

            [self.tableView1 reloadData];
       // }

    NSLog(@"cfraiparray %@", cFRAIPArray);



    NSLog(@"Succeeded!");



}
-(void)createPickerView :(UIButton *)button
{
    currentHotel=[self.objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];


    self.pickerViewTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pickerViewTextField];

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    weights= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1 Kg",@"2 Kg",@"5 Kg",@"10 Kg",@"50 Kg",
              nil];

    // set change the inputView (default is keyboard) to UIPickerView
    self.pickerViewTextField.inputView = pickerView;

    // add a toolbar with Cancel & Done button
    UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneTouched:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelTouched:)];
    [toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], doneButton, nil]];
    self.pickerViewTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;

    [self.pickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    //    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    //    [self bringUpPickerViewWithRow:indexPath];


}
-(void) deleteProduct:(UIButton *)button
{
    currentHotel=[self.objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webchefz.com/Andriod/delete.php?Table=Cart&CartID=%d&UserID=11",currentHotel.CartID]];



    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"main cart id is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentHotel.CartID]);
    NSLog(@"ded");

    [self.objectHolderArray removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];
    [self.tableView1 deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableView1 reloadData];
}

-(void) updateProduct:(UIButton *)button
{
    HUD= [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    HUD.labelText = @"Please Wait...";
    HUD.mode =  MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    [HUD show:YES];
    currentHotel=[self.objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.webchefz.com/Andriod/update.php?Table=Cart&CartID=%d&Quantity=%d&UserID=11&ProductID=%d",currentHotel.CartID,pickerQuantity,currentHotel.ProductID]];



    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"main cart id is %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentHotel.ProductID]);
    NSLog(@"ded%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentHotel.CartID]);
//    [self.tableView1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    //    [self.objectHolderArray removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
    self.tableView1.delegate = self;
    self.tableView1.dataSource = self;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:button.tag inSection:0];

    [self.tableView1 reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

   [self.tableView1 reloadData];


}

- (void)cancelTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    // hide the picker view
    [self.pickerViewTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)doneTouched:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    // hide the picker view
    [self.pickerViewTextField resignFirstResponder];

}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath ;
    if ([self.objectHolderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
    {


        if ([[weights objectAtIndex:row]isEqual:@"1 Kg"])
        {
            pickerQuantity=1;
            [self.pickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            [self.pickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

            selectWeight.hidden=YES;
            [self.tableView1 reloadData];

        }
        else if ([[weights objectAtIndex:row]isEqual:@"2 Kg"])
        {
            pickerQuantity=2;
            selectWeight.hidden=YES;
            [self.pickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

            [self.tableView1 reloadData];


        }
        else if ([[weights objectAtIndex:row]isEqual:@"5 Kg"])    {
            pickerQuantity=5;
            [self.pickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

            selectWeight.hidden=YES;
            [self.tableView1 reloadData];


        }
        else if ([[weights objectAtIndex:row]isEqual:@"10 Kg"])    {
            pickerQuantity=10;
            [self.pickerViewTextField becomeFirstResponder];

            selectWeight.hidden=YES;
            [self.tableView1 reloadData];


        }
        else{
            pickerQuantity=50;

            selectWeight.hidden=YES;
            [self.tableView1 reloadData];

        }}
    selectWeight.hidden=YES;

}
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 30;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

//---number of items(rows) in the Picker View---
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [weights count];
}




-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    //    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 30)];
    //    [self.view addSubview:selectWeight];
    //
    //
    //    // Get the text of the row.
    NSString *rowItem = [weights objectAtIndex: row];
    ////
    UILabel *lblRow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView bounds].size.width, 44.0f)];
    [lblRow setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    [lblRow setText:rowItem];
    lblRow.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];

    [lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    return lblRow;
}

@end
```

Comment: you are calling webservice and table reload at same...Actually either you shoud put reload data in main queue or after fetching response of webservice..

Answer (score 0):

You should just call [tableView reloadData], to update info inside table view each time.